# Jest unit testing API using express and mongoose

Tags: javascript, express, mongoose, tdd, jestjs

I am trying a TDD approach on an user API. I wanted to integrated unit tests for my functions: userRegister and userLogin

This is my app.js

```
'use strict'

const express = require('express')
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')
const passport = require('passport')
const users = require('../routes/users')


const app = express()
const port = 5000

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
   res.send({ msg: 'Test' })
})

//BodyParser Middleware
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }))
app.use(bodyParser.json())

//Passport middleware
app.use(passport.initialize())

//Initialize Routes

app.use('/api/users', users)

//Export app

module.exports = app
```

This is my userController.js:

```
'use strict'

const express = require('express')
const bcrypt = require('bcryptjs')
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken')
const keys = require('../../../../config/keys')
const passport = require('passport')
const status = require('http-status-codes')

const User = require('../../models/User')


module.exports.test = (req, res) => {
    res.json({msg: 'Users works'})
}

module.exports.userRegister = (req, res) => {
    User.findOne({ email: req.body.email})
        .then(user => {
            if(user)
                return res.status(400).json({ userEmailerror: 'Email already 
exists'})
            else{
                const newUser = new User({
                    name: req.body.name,
                    email: req.body.email,
                    password: req.body.password
                })

                newUser.save()
                    .then(user => res.json(user))
                    .catch(err => console.log(err))

            }
        })
}
```

this is my userController.test.js

```
'use strict'

const mongoose = require('mongoose')
const testUserDB = require('../../../config/keys').testUsersMongURI
mongoose.connect(testUserDB)

const userController = require('../modules/controllers/userController')
const User = require('../models/User')

describe('register new user', () => {
    test('succesfully register a valid user', () => {
        const newUser = new User({
            name: 'test',
            email: 'test@gmail.com',
            password: 'test123'
        })
        const req = {body: {newUser}}

        userController.userRegister(req).then(user => {
            expect(user.name).toBe('test')
            expect(user.email).toBe('test@gmail.com')

        })


    })

})
```

The script I use to run the test is:

```
"test": "jest --coverage",
```

I am new to Javascript and Full stack and the error I received is confusing me

```
 RUNS  src/user/__tests__/userController.test.js
 FAIL  src/user/__tests__/userController.test.js
  register new user
    × succesfully register a valid user (19ms)

  ● register new user › succesfully register a valid user

    TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined

  16 |              })
  17 |              const req = {body: {newUser}}
> 18 |              userController.userRegister(req).then(user => {
     |              ^
  19 |                      expect(user.name).toBe('test')
  20 |                      expect(user.email).toBe('test@gmail.com')
  21 |

  at Object.test (src/user/__tests__/userController.test.js:18:3)
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: The test is telling you the right thing: `userController.userRegister` doesn't actually return anything.

Comment: I tried returning in various ways but I got same error.

Answer (score 0):

userRegister does not return a promise, so you can chain a .then
You may want to save what it returns in a variable and check with that value.

```
let createdUser = userController.userRegister(req)
expect(createdUser.name).toBe('test')
expect(createdUser.email).toBe('test@gmail.com')
```